Is there a way to do compile time checks within a constexpr function?
I was trying to write a log function in C++ that is evaluated at compile time. I would like for the code to compile and give an answer only when the input is a power of 2. To accomplish I need some way to perform checks within a constexpr function during compile time.
I would like the following behavior:
constexpr int a = logBase2(16); // should equal 4
constexpr int b = logBase2(42); // should not compile, input is not a power of 2
constexpr int c = logBase2(-1); // should also not compile

I tried the following code:
constexpr bool isPowerOf2(int x) {
    return (x > 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0);
}

constexpr int logBase2(int x) {
    static_assert(isPowerOf2(x), "Input must be a power of 2");

    int result = 0;
    while ((x & 1) == 0) {
        x >>= 1;
        result++;
    }

    return result;
}

Of course this doesn't compile, because the parameter x is not guaranteed to be constexpr: constexpr just means that the function can be evaluated at compile time.
I would need something like this:
constexpr bool isPowerOf2(int x) {
return (x > 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0);
}

constexpr int logBase2(constexpr int x) { // x must be able to be evaluated at compile time
static_assert(isPowerOf2(x), "Input must be a power of 2");

    int result = 0;
    while ((x & 1) == 0) {
        x >>= 1;
        result++;
    }
    
    return result;

}

But this isn't valid C++. Is there any way to accomplish this or something analogous?

if you only ever want the function to run at compile time you can make it a consteval function.  That does require C++20 or newer.

You just need to perform any action that is not permitted in a constant expression if your requirement isn't satisfied, e.g.: Call a non-constexpr function, dereference a null pointer, fail an assert, throw an exception, etc. Which one is the best choice, I am not sure myself. You would then probably like to make the function consteval instead of constexpr as well, so that nobody will be able to accidentally call it at runtime with incorrect behavior.

I think I would go with if(!isPowerOf2(x)) std::abort();. Together with consteval that should be safe, and without it you'll get a crash like an assert (but in debug and release mode) if someone accidentally calls it with an invalid value in a context that isn't purely compile-time evaluated. If crashing isn't safe for you, throwing something like std::invalid_argument might be better.

Making x as a template parameter as shown here is another option.

You might throw (or any non-constexpr "thing") in case of "error", then you will have compilation error.
constexpr bool isPowerOf2(int x) {
    return (x > 0) && ((x & (x - 1)) == 0);
}

constexpr int logBase2(int x) {
    if (!isPowerOf2(x)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Input must be a power of 2");
    }

    int result = 0;
    while ((x & 1) == 0) {
        x >>= 1;
        result++;
    }

    return result;
}

then
constexpr int b = logBase2(42); // not compile
constexpr int c = logBase2(-1); // not compile


That works, thanks. But I don't fully understand how a throw can happen at compile time...

@puff_the_magic_dragon It can't (at least in the current specification of constant expressions). That's why it fails to compile.

The risk I see with throwing exceptions is that at some point they might become allowed in constant expressions. Although I guess they probably wouldn't be allowed across compile-time/runtime boundary. If something like that was to happen, code like this wouldn't continue to work as intended.

The functions you want are already in the standard library, in the <bit> header (introduced in C++20).
std::has_single_bit() will tell you if its argument is a power of 2. std::countr_zero() will then tell you the log base 2.

But they don't also verify their argument to be a power-of-two.

That's what has_single_bit() does.

The problem is to make it impossible for the function to be accidentally called with a value that isn't a power of two, at least in compile-time contexts. Checking the value beforehand at each call site is not a solution to the problem.

If the function is supposed to always be evaluated at compile-time, you should either define as consteval, or a template with all value arguments as NTTP.
First include common headers:
#include <bit>
#include <limits>
#include <concepts>
#incluce <cstdints>
#incluce <type_traits>

Next:

consteval function:

#include <stdexcept>

auto constexpr power_error_v = std::numeric_limits<std::uint16_t>::max();
template<std::unsigned_integral int_t, bool do_throw = true>
consteval std::uint16_t true_log2(int_t const n, std::bool_constant<do_throw>={}){
    if (std::has_single_bit(n)
        return std::uint16_t{countr_zero(n)};

    if  constexpr(do_throw)
        throw std::invalid_argument{"not an exact power of 2."};
    else
        return power_error_v;
};

Throwing in compiletime context is considered a compile error. You can bypass the compile error using std::false_type as the second function argument:
constexpr auto shift = true_log2(42, std::false_type{});
static_assert(shift == power_error_v);
  

If you wish to be able to use true_log2 with runtime values you can define it as constexpr instead. Otherwise you have the option to use variable tenplate as well:
template<std::unsigned_integral auto n>
requires std::has_single_bit(n)
constexpr std::integral_constant
        < std::uint16_t
        , std::uint16_t{std::countr_zero(n)}
        > true_log2;

I could've used std::uint16_t as the value type:
constexpr auto true_log2 =
          std::uint16_t{std::countr_zero(n)};

But std::integral_constant has stronger constness properties; I can check the type at compile-time in meta programming contexts, to assure constness of the result.
